# RE: HELP! Google cloud DNS problems

Tags: domain-name-system, cloud, google

I love google cloud hosting..My domain DNS Zones is not propagating for more than 7 days now and it's pointing to google cloud servers.

I have contacted namecheap and they said i should check google cloud support.

Domain:   [www.animalslink.com](http://www.animalslink.com)    http://35.184.211.188

Can anybody please tell me why my DNS is not propagating?

Thanks

Abraham

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that the domain is still pointed to namecheap DNS servers. If you wish to use Google Cloud DNS, make sure you create the domain in your Google Cloud Control Panel. When you do this, they will assign your domain to two Google Cloud DNS servers. You need to copy or write down those two DNS servers. Once you have those, goto your namecheap account, edit the domain's DNS servers. Replace the namecheap servers with your google Cloud DNS servers that were assigned.